# Grammatically correct but short version of question

Tags: grammar, questions, marketing

I want to state a question in the shortest and most effective way possible without making it grammatically incorrect.

The question to ask is:

> If my employees and I don't take a break, why should the machines?

I feel something is missing at the end but not sure.

Comment: What's missing is the repeated verb phrase _take a break,_ deleted by Conjunction Reduction. Repetition is a form of emphasis. Why delete _take a break_ from the second clause, when that's the focus of the question? _If my employees and I don't take a break, why should the machines take a break?_ is much more emphatic and leaves the question hanging there, complete.

Comment: Better yet: *Why should the machines take a break, if my employees and I don't?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to shorten the question further would be to make the comparison more fundamental as in:

If *humans* don't take a break, why should *machines*?

This minimal form increases the polarity of the issue.
Short, simple questions are considered by some to be effective.

I believe the question is grammatically correct.